# Export oracle database data through java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, export

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to set up my database. The way I currently backup my database data is through SQL Developer. (Right click on tablename > export)
Which will give me a .sql file.

But, how do I do this through java code? I've looked into expdp, but I don't know how to execute it through my code, if that's even the right way to do it.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: you want run the exported db file in java

Comment: No, I want to export the data of my database, the question is how.

Answer (score 0):

Data Pump can be automated through the standard package [DBMS_DATAPUMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_datpmp.htm#i1007277).  You could build a small PL/SQL procedure and call that procedure from Java.  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_api.htm#i1006925) is an example of exporting a schema with DBMS_DATAPUMP, but it does not look very intuitive.